# Android Emulator showing blank screen

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-virtual-device, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using Nexus 5 API 22 Android Emulator in Vmware .
My computer RAM is 4 GB and I have alloted 2 GB to VMWare.
Out of this 2 GB I have alloted 786 MB to Vmware and 768 to AVD.

When I run my emulator it just show a blank screen with a keyboard, nothing loading, no indication.

Ho can I solve this issue , is my RAM low or something else ?

Comment: I hope you are giving it enough time to load.

Comment: @AANKIT its been 30 minutes :)

Comment: Then, there is definitely some error.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you have to check the option "Use host GPU" in the AVD configuration